# What does Islam say about Samson?

Tags: prophets, bible, judaism, torah

I recently saw a trailer about a biblical person named Samson. I have not heard anything similar in the Islamic scriptures.

URL: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mSolF3QBVBY

Do we reject the story or simply ignore it as the Prophet was silent about it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Quran and authentic hadith do not mention [Samson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samson). So we can't make a decisive claim on the authenticity of his story in the Bible.

Samson ( شمسون ) is briefly mentioned in some Islamic traditions, possibly deriving from Isra'iliyyat:

> وقال ابن مسعود : إن النبي - صلى الله عليه وسلم - ذكر رجلا من بني إسرائيل لبس السلاح في سبيل الله ألف شهر ; فعجب المسلمون من ذلك ; فنزلت إنا أنزلناه الآية . خير من ألف شهر ، التي لبس فيها الرجل سلاحه في سبيل الله . ونحوه عن ابن عباس .
>
> Ibn Masud said: The Prophet told us of a person from the Bani Israel who who fought Jihad in the way of Allah for a thousand months. When the people were worried by it the verse: "*The Night of Decree is better than a thousand months.*
> [[97:3]](https://quran.com/97/3)" was revealed, and this night is better than the thousand months in which he waged Jihad. Similar to this is narrated from Ibn Abbas.
>
> وهب بن منبه : إن ذلك الرجل كان مسلما ، وإن أمه جعلته نذرا لله ، وكان من قرية قوم يعبدون الأصنام ، وكان سكن قريبا منها ; فجعل يغزوهم وحده ، ويقتل ويسبي ويجاهد ، وكان لا يلقاهم إلا بلحيي بعير ، وكان إذا قاتلهم وقاتلوه وعطش ، انفجر له من اللحيين ماء عذب ، فيشرب منه ، وكان قد أعطي قوة في البطش ، لا يوجعه حديد ولا غيره : وكان اسمه شمسون
>
> [Wahb ibn Munabbih](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wahb_ibn_Munabbih) said: He was a Muslim. When he was born his mother vowed this to Allah. They lived near a people who were idolators. He waged war alone ... with the jaw-bones of a camel, when he thirsted water came out from between the jaws, he was given strength and iron didn't hurt him. His name was Shamson.
>
> <sup>— [Tafsir Qurtubi](http://quran.ksu.edu.sa/tafseer/qortobi/sura97-aya3.html)</sup>

Tabari also mentions Samson in his Tarikh [here](https://shamela.ws/book/9783/463) and [here](https://shamela.ws/book/9783/647), with details similar to the Biblical narrative, though the chronology may be messed up.

Comment: The links for Tabari's references are dead. Could you please update?

Answer (score 0):

This story been told in Qasas-u l-Anbiyaa book, that in one particular moment prophet Muhammad SAW (PBUH) smiling by himself, a friend ask him, "What makes you smile o' Rasulullah?"

Rasulullah answered : "It has been showed to me in the end of day when all mankind gathered in Mahsyar. All prophet and Rasul gathered with his follower, enter the Heaven. There's a prophet with a sword, who doesn't have any followers, enters the Heaven, he is Sam'un (Samson)”

Comment: There are quite a few notable Qasas Ul Anbiya books, will you point out which one (by stating the author) you are talking about and the reference of this in the book? Jazak Allah khair.